# Quadratic equation variables

Tags: quadratics

> Suppose that $3+2\sqrt2$ solves $x^2-6x+a=0$. Find the value of $a$.
>
> - a) $1$
> - b) $3$
> - c) $5$
> - d) $6$

option e) is cut out of the picture and it is $8$.

I want a step by step explanation on how to solve this.

Comment: Just plug in $x = 3 + 2 \sqrt{2}$ into $x^2 - 6 x + a = 0$ and get an equation in $a$.  Then solve it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555154/the-conjugate-roots-theorem-for-irrational-roots

Comment: Okay, and what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If irrational roots are there for a quadratic then they occur in pairs this can be verified by Descartes rule and by simple quadratic formula
 x=( -b +/- √(b²-4ac) )/2a if one root is radical then other also is a radical and its conjugate. Now according to your question 3+2√2 is a root so must be 3 - 2√2. Now we know that a equals product of roots in the equation, so simply (3+2√2)(3-2√2) gives your answer which equals 3² - (2√2)² = 1